# Registration into default group is not working as expected

Tags: registration, user-groups

Here are my settings for user registration:
\ 
[image: User settings]

When front end registration completes the users are added fine but not into the default user group as expected. They are just in the system with no group.
I was expecting them to be registered into the default group - am i missing something?

Comment: Were you logged-in whilst testing this? If so, the new user will be created, but not assigned to the "default" group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get bit by this a *lot*.
Just like @Stephen Lewis suggested - make sure you are not logged into the same browser.

For example, log into the CP with Safari (or whatever) and then use Chrome to actually register an account via your front-end form.

Comment: perfect - thank you